# Use API3 or API4?

Tags: api

What is the recommended version of API to use at this point in time? I am about to do a major rewrite of an extension to manage small groups and I want to future proof it.

Are there any advantages/disadvantages to using API4?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coleman sent the following to the [dev list 3 weeks ago](https://lists.civicrm.org/lists/arc/civicrm-dev/2018-07/msg00006.html).  The line I have emphasised below seems particularly relevant to your question.

> As you probably know, CiviCRM api v4 has been quietly being developed
>   over in an extension. The nice thing about being in an extension is
>   that we can commit code without going through the core PR process and
>   iterate rapidly, but the downside is that it doesn't get as much
>   attention or visibility.
>
> But that's about to change. I intend for CiviCRM 5.5 to ship with the
>   Api4 extension bundled in the tarball. At first it will be disabled by
>   default, but at some point that too will change.
>
> It has a test suite that is being run on a nightly basis here:
>   https://test.civicrm.org/view/All/job/CiviCRM-Ext-Matrix/ (soon I want
>   api4 tests running with every core PR).
>
> I've now developed my first extension using api4, and I'm happy enough
>   with it to start recommending that other developers give it a try. **IMO
>   if you are starting off writing a new extension and want to ensure
>   longevity for that project, api4 is a good choice (even though we
>   currently have no plans to deprecate api3, someday it may happen).**
>
> So I suggest you download the api4 extension and play around with the
>   new, angular-based api explorer to have a look at what it can do (the
>   explorer is not 100% feature-complete but it's still fun to play
>   with). Enjoy :)

Advantages: intended to be lots!
Disadvantages: it's new.

Comment: I will certainly have a play with it :-)

Answer (score 3):

As long as the Developer Guide (https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/api/) only mentions API3 I would recommned using that one.